# Как правильно - разрезная или нарезная балка?

Tags: перевод, значения, выбор-слова

Встретилось словосочетание "нарезные балки", мне нужно его перевести на английский, но чтобы перевести, нужно понять. В интернете встречается очень мало результатов поиска по "нарезная балка", однако "разрезная балка" довольно часто. Возможно правильно назвать балку "разрезной", нежели "нарезной" - это вообще одно и то же?

Вот здесь нарезная:

> На данный момент популярны многопролётные, консольные, однопролётные и нарезные металлические балки. Невзирая на такое разнообразие балок, по популярности с большим отрывом идёт именно нарезная металлическая балка.

А [здесь](http://2stroy.ru/help/160/492.html) разрезная:

> Разрезная балка - это балка имеющая две опоры и перекрывающая один
>   пролет. А неразрезная балка - это та балка, которая имеет несколько
>   опор и перекрывающая несколько пролетов. От качества изготовления
>   балки и ее установки, зависит прочность  и устойчивость здания.

Comment: Может это два термина? "Нарезной" обычно относится к наличию резьбы (например нарезное оружие), а "разрезной" — к не-монолитности (н-р разрезной мост у автомобиля)

Comment: Судя по нескольким находкам "нарезная" - это цельная балка на нескольких опорах (напр. здесь: http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/1925763/page:7/ или здесь http://www.stroim31.ru/dict/1/%D0%9D).

Comment: @Artemix
Она может быть как на двух, так и на нескольких опорах. Одной опоры у балки быть не может. Если чисто логически подумать.

Comment: Вот вам пожалуйста - балка с одной опорой: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Тогда на одной или больше опорах. Но суть вопроса не в этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего в балках не понимаю,но, даже,судя по вашим цитатам, это разные вещи. И вот еще одна цитата, говорящая о том же.

> Разрезной балкой называют ту, которая перекрывает только **один** пролет и имеет пару опор. А нарезная многопролетная балка это та, которая перекрывает **несколько** пролетов и имеет также несколько опорных точек.

Continuous stringer дает мультитран.
Еще цитата

> Простейшими конструктивными элементами и одновременно простейшими горизонтальной и вертикальной конструктивными системами являются балка и стойка (столб, колонна). Балка представляет собой прямой брус, опирающийся на две или более количества опор. Балка, свободно лежащая на двух опорах, перекрывающая один пролет, называется разрезной; балка, перекрывающая несколько пролетов, т.е. лежащая на многих опорах, называется нарезной многопролетной; балка, заделанная в опору одним концом и свободная на другом, называется консолью.

Comment: В зависмости от размера балки, также может быть "continuous girder".  Girder - основная балка.  Stringer - дополнительная балка.

Comment: @V.V. В вашем ответе есть объяснение того, что не обязательно они и разные. Даже в моём вопросе есть разъяснение
`На данный момент популярны многопролётные, консольные, однопролётные и нарезные металлические балки`.
Значит балки могут быть нарезными/разрезными, но это не отменяет того, что и та и другая (в случае если они разные) могут быть как одно- так и много- пролётными.

Comment: Еще одну добавила цитату.

Comment: В этом случае разница ясна. Только это ещё больше путает. Но за ответ спасибо.

Comment: И всё-таки мне кажется, что балки должны быть разрезными. А нарезные - ошибка. Потому что иначе получается какая-то муть, если подумать.

Comment: Вторая цитата из учебника. Нарезная =неразрезная.

Answer (score 3):

Вспомнился сопромат...  Со специальности (и тех. перевода) помню, что именно continuous girder и continuous stringer. И те и другие являются continuous beams,  а так же collector beams. Это горизонтальные балки, имеющие более чем две опоры. Разница в том, что stringer опираются на girders, в то время как последние могут быть "ненарезными" - разрезными, вторые как правило нарезные.

Реально stringer используется гораздо реже как слово в значении балка в сочетании с continuous, так как правило они являются нарезными.

Возможно что-то непонятно, но "нарезной" и "неразрезной" в этом случае с инженерной точки зрения - полные синонимы. ГОСТом установлен термин "многопролетная неразрезная балка", однако термин "нарезная" балка продолжает встречаться.

Comment: Да, но вопрос в том как правильно: "нарезная" или "разрезная". И означают ли эти два варианта разные балки или одну (неразрезные не трогаем)?

Comment: @Vladimir Markiev нарезная это _неразрезная_ балка с опорами, не создающими моментов (то есть, эквивалентыми шарнирам)